# How to tell if a DOM element is displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

This is not to be confused with ["How to tell if a DOM element is visible?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible)

I want to determine if a given DOM element is visible on the page.
E.g. if the element is a child of a parent which has `display:none;` set, then it won't be visible.

(This has nothing to do with whether the element is in the viewport or not)

I could iterate through each parent of the element, checking the `display` style, but I'd like to know if there is a more direct way?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From a quick test in Firefox, it looks like the size and position properties (clientWidth, offsetTop etc.) all return 0 when an element is hidden by a parent being `display:none`.

Comment: Good idea. It's even specified: http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#offset-attributes

Comment: In the current CSSOM View Module draft (2013) the link posted by @Kornel does not point to the right section anymore. Check out [w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsettop](http://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsettop).

Answer (score 1):

Using [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org):

```
if($('someDiv').visible) {...}
```

Comment: It would have been more helpful if you had provided the source code for this function of Prototype, to show how it could actually be done.

Comment: I only use the library. I didn't write it.

Answer (score 0):

As I'm using [MochiKit](http://mochikit.com/), what I came up with based on Ant P's answer was:

```
getElementPosition('mydiv').y != 0
```

I can also check whether it's in the viewport (vertically) by:

```
y = getElementPosition('mydiv').y
(y < getViewportPosition().y + getViewportDimensions().h &&
    getViewportPosition().y < y)
```

Incidentally this also works in IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on the position being 0 is brittle. You're better off writing a helper function to iterate through the parents to check their display style directly.

Comment: Care to elaborate? If it's in the standard, supported by the standards-compliant crowd (FF, WebKit, …), and supported by the non-compliant gorilla, what makes it brittle?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the iterative solution  -

```
var elementShown = function(e){
    if (e == document) 
      return true;

    if ($(e).css('display') == 'none') //or whatever your css function is
      return false;

    return elementShown(e.parentNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.getClientRects()` will return an empty array if the element is not displayed by inheritance (`display="none"` from parent/ancestor element)